# Out of Memory exception when retrieving Images from Website Link url

Tags: android-layout, exception, memory-leaks, imageview, android-drawable

Hello i am creating an android application , and i have on  my website about more than 1500 photos that i want to display on a ListView using an Array adapter 
One solution i found is downloading the images from a URL link i have . 
Here is the stacktrace

**My problem is that i get an Out of Memory exception**

> : E/AndroidRuntime(1123): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-79
>   : E/AndroidRuntime(1123): Process:
>   android.quotations, PID: 1123
>   ** : E/AndroidRuntime(1123): **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**  : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):
>     at** android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
>   : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:613)
>    : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):    at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:589)
>   : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
>    : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):    at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
>    : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):    at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:791)
>    : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):    at
>   com.c.fragments.AuthorImageFragment.loadImageFromWebOperations(AuthorImageFragment.java:77)
>   : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at
>   com.c.fragments.AuthorImageFragment.access$0(AuthorImageFragment.java:72)
>    : E/AndroidRuntime(1123):    at
>   com.c.fragments.AuthorImageFragment$1.run(AuthorImageFragment.java:109)

**and here is the code from the adapter:**

```
private ImageView imageDetail(View v, int resId, Drawable drawable) { 
        ImageView value = (ImageView) v.findViewById(resId); 
        BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable)drawable;
//      value.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        Bitmap  bmp=draw.getBitmap();
       // value.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams((width/4), (height/4)));
        value.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        return value; 

    }





Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Author author;
                   // This is just a test i want to do :)))
                   for (int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
                       author=new Author();

                       try {
                        author.setAuthorImage(loadImageFromWebOperations("http://mySite/Directory/images/"+5+".jpg",i));
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                       list.add(author);  
                   }
                   getActivity().runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){ 
                        public void run() {
                            adapter= new AuthorImageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),list);
                        }
                   });
          }
        };  networkThread.start();
```

****Here is the Method i use to retrieve the Image****

```
private Drawable loadImageFromWebOperations(String url,int id) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
        { InputStream is=null;
              try{
            is = (InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent();
            LOGGER.info("Drawable -----");
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, id+".jpg");
            return d;
          }catch (Exception e) {
           // log Exception
        LOGGER.info("Exception "+e.toString());
           return null;
          }
              finally {
                  if (is!=null){
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        LOGGER.info("Exception "+e.toString());
     // log Exception
                         return null;
                    }
              }
              }
        }
```

any help would be appreciated ..
Best regards :))) 
Now to help more i will add the code i use to retrieve the images .

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you're going to be able to hold that many images in memory. I'd suggest that you download the images to local file storage and then in your Adapter when you want to actually draw the item that has the image, you should kick off a Loader that will load the image from disk on-demand. Sorry, there's just not enough memory to store that many images at once.

A more advanced strategy is to insert a cache using WeakReferences into the loading process. You load the image from disk and insert into something like a HashMap> and see if the image you want is in there first and if not, then do a load from disk as you normally would.

If you want to get architecturally really fancy what happens is the WeakReference cache I list above, try to load from disk, but if the file isn't present on disk only then load from the network. This then becomes a two-tier cache memory, then disk, before finally hitting the web.